# Is there an easy way to combine strings as function parameter?

Tags: c++, string

Let's say I have a C++ function

```
void foo(std::string str) {
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

Now, in the equivalent Java I could call the function with a combination of various types and it would automatically be concatenated, for example:

```
foo("test " + intValue + " " + stringValue + "...");
```

This does not work in C++, but is there a way in modern C++ to achieve the same? The only solution I have found is to create a `stringstream` variable and do the concatenation there. However, that seems like a lot of overhead for such a common use case.

Comment: C++ is not as high a level language like Java and C#. So if you want to use C++ you will need to put in more effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `std::stringstream` in a function and use that:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


void foo(std::string){}

template<typename...Args>
std::string concat(Args&&...args){
    std::stringstream ss;
    (ss << ... << args);
    return ss.str();
}

int main(){
    int intValue=12;
    std::string stringValue="hello";
    foo(concat("test ",intValue," ",stringValue,"..."));
}
```

`std::string` supports concatenation by `+`, but primitives types do not. So, you can wrap them in `std::to_string` but that is not so nice.

Allowing `"hello"+5` is too dangerous because `"hello"` is one easy step from being `const char*` which would trigger pointer arithmetic instead.

From C++20, there is `std::format`.

Comment: Thank you, `std::format` seems indeed ideal - too bad it isn't supported in Visual Studio yet. And yes, as I've written in the OP, right now I'm using `stringstream`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a string builder class that wrapps the boilerplate of the `std::stringstream` a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct Builder {

    std::stringstream s;

    template<typename T>
    Builder(const T& x) {
        s << x;
    }

    template<typename T>
    friend Builder&& operator+(Builder&& b, const T& val) {
        b.s << val;
        return std::move(b);
    }

    operator std::string() const {
        return s.str();
    }
};
```

Call site could use it like this:

```
foo(Builder("test ") + 3 + " " + "stringValue" + "...");
```

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/KG7as9).

Comment: Yes, I'm doing something like that already, but was hoping to have something simpler / more efficient.

Comment: Cool. Please consider including this kind of information into your future questions so that people willing to help you don't waste their time.

Comment: I did say the following: "The only solution I have found is to create a `stringstream` variable and do the concatenation there." - I'm not sure how else I should have made clear that I'm aware of a solution like that. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by using `to_string()` on integer values.

```
foo("test " + to_string(intValue) + " " + stringValue + "...");
```